# Changing style of Previous & next elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a form on a webpage, but i don't have access to the HTML or CSS of the page.  So any manipulation has to be done with Javascript\JQuery.

the form looks like this:
[image]

And I'm trying to change the styling on some elements before & after the "Company Name" (input) field.  I can identify\target this field\element as it has a unique id, and i already have some code which is changing the styling of this element.  The id of this element is "parentcustomerid_name".

Using inspection in the browser i get this HTML (the 'parentcustomerid_name' element is selected).

The div with the class "input-group" immediately above it (lower tree) i want to add the style of 'width:100%'.

The div with the class "input-group-btn" below it, i want to add the style of 'display:none' (the purpose is to hide the 2 buttons).

I can't target those element's by there class as it would effect other fields like "Prefix".
[image]

I don't believe i could use 'previousSibling' as it's on a different tree level.
I don't believe i could use 'nextSibling' as it would return a hidden input field.
(well in testing im having issues)

at the moment this is the code i have - its just disabling the field (so nothing can be entered/selected), as disabling the field removed the border i added it back in, and as disabling the field also removed padding before the text i added that in.  Obviously as im disabling the field then i want to remove the buttons on the right hand side as they still function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
document.getElementById("parentcustomerid_name").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("parentcustomerid_name").style.padding = "0px 0px 0px 12px";
document.getElementById("parentcustomerid_name").style.border = "1px solid #949494";
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try document.getElementById("parentcustomerid_name").parentNode.style.width = "the witdth you want"

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Or: `document.querySelector('#parentcustomerid_name').closest('.input-group')`

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the input-group-btn. For that, as you have the parent, just query the className (Only do this if you do not have multiple input-group-btn as siblings. 

document.getElementById("parentcustomerid_name").parentNode.querySelector(".input-group-btn").style.display = "none"

Comment: thanks heaps Milan.  Got them both working :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Milan Lakhani
comments above i got the answer:

```
document.getElementById("parentcustomerid_name").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("parentcustomerid_name").style.padding = "0px 0px 0px 12px";
document.getElementById("parentcustomerid_name").style.border = "1px solid #949494";
document.getElementById("parentcustomerid_name").parentNode.style.width = "100%";
document.getElementById("parentcustomerid_name").parentNode.querySelector(".input-group-btn").style.display = "none";
```

this is how the form looks now:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can query for the closest parent with a particular class:

```js
const group = document
  .querySelector('#parentcustomerid_name')
  .closest('.input-group');

group.classList.add('altered');
```

```css
.altered {
  background: red;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.altered .input-group-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <div class="input-group" role="none">
    <input id="parentcustomerid_name" class="form-control" />
    <div class="input-group-button">
      <button type="button">Clear</button>
      <button type="button">Open</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, you can use CSS; although this is still experimental:

```css
.control:has(.input-group) {
  background: red;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.control:has(.input-group) .input-group-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <div class="input-group" role="none">
    <input id="parentcustomerid_name" class="form-control" />
    <div class="input-group-button">
      <button type="button">Clear</button>
      <button type="button">Open</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since you don't have control of the CSS, you can inject a script tag:

```js
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
  <style type="text/css">
    .control:has(.input-group) {
      background: red;
      padding: 1rem;
    }
    .control:has(.input-group) .input-group-button {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
`);
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <div class="input-group" role="none">
    <input id="parentcustomerid_name" class="form-control" />
    <div class="input-group-button">
      <button type="button">Clear</button>
      <button type="button">Open</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```